# Is it possible for OWASP ZAP to pass-through some requests without intercepting them, as if there were no proxy?

Tags: penetration-test, zap, certificate-pinning

I have an iOS app with certificate pinning to two different servers.

I want to test this certificate pinning with a MITM attack, so I did:

1. Set proxy at my PC, in macos wifi settings -> advanced -> proxies -> enabled http/https proxy.
2. Installed Dynamic SSL cert on simulator.
3. It works, I can see https data when I open some webpage in Safari.
4. Run the app. App doesn't work (because one of this two certificate pinnings did work).
5. I'm unable to test the second certificate pinning.

Is it possible to disable proxying for one URL and enable for second? Make some requests go straight to desired URL, with SSL certificate at that URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup we have an FAQ for that: https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/what-options-exist-for-selective-proxying/

Options include:

1. Via a Browser Add-on/Extension
2. Via Global Excludes
3. Via a PAC (Proxy Auto-Config) File
4. Set “No Proxy For” in Your Browser

Comment: 1 and 4 won't work for me, since I'm not using browser. Tried 2: added Global Exclude URL ^.*$ and enabled. It still uses OWASP Zed Attack Proxy Root CA (for this page right now in macos chrome browser, for example). Will try to set up PAC in macos wifi settings.

Comment: PAC did work, although PAC setup on macos does not work with file:/// -- easiest solution was "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000". Also, I've noticed macos network has exception list under "Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains", this works too.

Comment: Glad one of the options worked for you, thanks for following up with additional details too. That'll help others in the future.